# selecting a particular index from an array in react

Tags: reactjs

I am making an axios call to fetch certain data and store that data in a list called urls by updating the state , However when i click on any particular item from the list , that corresponding index should be fetched so that i can store it in a state and pass it to child component . Not sure how exactly to accomplish this .

```
constructor(props){
   super(props);
   this.state={
     urls:[],
     selectedUrl : ''
    }
  }
componentDidMount(){
axios.get(`http://localhost:8200/service/${this.service_name}`)
  .then(  response=> {
    console.log(response.data);
    this.setState({
      urls:response.data.urls
    })
  })
}

selectedUrlHandler(i){
   console.log('before clicked',i,this.state)
   this.setState((state)=>({
      selectedUrl:state.urls[i]
       }) , ()=>{ console.log(this.state.selectedUrl)});
   console.log('after clicked',i,this.state)
}

render(){
   return(
       {
            this.state.urls.map( (list,i) => {
              return(
                <tr key={index}>
                <td>
                    <Link to={{pathname:`/service/${this.service_name}/requests`, 
                                state:{url:this.state.selectedUrl}}} 
                                onClick={()=>this.selectedUrlHandler(i)}>{list}</Link>
                </td>
                </tr>
              );
            })
          }
    )
}
```

As above in the selectedUrlHandler i want to fetch the index of a particular item clicked and update the selectedUrl state .

As you can see from the screenshot , the console.log inside setState is not getting accessed at all.
[image]

Any help appreciated , Thank you .

Comment: this index value you set it into  child key component, because key is unique in all react dom

Comment: I am using a map function as well in the child component , not sure as to how to pass it exactly .

Comment: There's two things here. First, you are using a Link tag, which is going to load the component with the matching route, which may not be what you want. Second, you're passing a local variable "index" to the onClick handler. Change (index) to () and you should have what you want.

Comment: @Jayavel : so my selectedUrl will be something like this - selectedUrl:this.state.urls[index] ?

Comment: @CodySwann - but can we pass that index to the child component ?

Comment: @nishant are you looking for a solution like this https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-zns6qs   ?

Comment: @Jayavel - yes its similar , but when i try it , the setState is not getting updated at all  , the flow is not at all entering this.setState method

Comment: @Jayavel - have updated my query along with screenshot and what i tried , please have a look once .

Comment: @Jayavel -  yes had tried that , this.state.selectedUrl shows nothing , i kept state so that if anything gets updated it can be displayed , but its not working .

Comment: @nishant can you check my stackblitz and check console once that's the correct console print

Comment: @nishant To achieve that remove the Link component and define the onClick event on li

Comment: @Jayavel - yes thats correct , but i don know where i am going wrong now , my code is almost the same except for the axios part ...

Comment: @Jayavel if Using li , can we pass the same way as props such as pathname , state are passed ?

Comment: two possible solutions : 1. use history.push to change the route dynamically. 2. <Link to  state:{url:this.state.selectedUrl}}} here this.state.urls[i] do like this

Comment: i tried the second solution , it is working  - Thank you , any idea why this.state.selectedUrl was not working correctly ? I am not able to figure why it was working .

Comment: Yes , sure , will do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two possible solutions :

1. use history.push to change the route dynamically.Instead,  you can use li and define the onClick event on li.
2. change `state:{url:this.state.selectedUrl}` to  `state:{url: this.state.urls[i]}`

In first solution, Link is already has an internal hanlder for clicking which is redirection to another Route. So If you need to use onClick on it, you need

```
<Link 
    to="/item" 
    onClick={(e) => this.changeRoutePath(e)}>
    Prevent 
</Link>

changeRoutePath(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.history.push(this.props.match.path);
}
```

In second solution, Since your mapping all the urls, you can directly pass an index to `this.state.urls[i]` get current url.

Hope it helps.